# How to change a classification model to a regression model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, regression

I am using pre-trained Alexnet as shown below. I want to use that model for regression with 6 outputs (Xcoordinate (range (0,227),Ycoordinate (range (0,227),height (range (20,50), width (range (20,50), sine(theta), cos(theta)). (range of theta is -180 to 180 degrees)
These are the following things I change -

1. changed loss function to MSE.
2. changed the output layer from 1000 to 6.
3. changed from RELU to linear activation function last layer.

Now, I am not getting proper valued of sine and cosine above (it should be in the range of (-1 to 1)), I am getting out of bound values. What should I do, How should I keep a bound one the values. Also, should I keep a bout on other parameters as well. What should I do incorporate those changes?
What are the other changes should I make to use this model for regression.?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

class AlexNet(object):

  def __init__(self, x, keep_prob, num_classes, skip_layer,
               weights_path = 'DEFAULT'):

    # Parse input arguments into class variables
    self.X = x
    self.NUM_CLASSES = num_classes
    self.KEEP_PROB = keep_prob
    self.SKIP_LAYER = skip_layer

    if weights_path == 'DEFAULT':
      self.WEIGHTS_PATH = 'bvlc_alexnet.npy'
    else:
      self.WEIGHTS_PATH = weights_path

    # Call the create function to build the computational graph of AlexNet
    self.create()

  def create(self):

    # 1st Layer: Conv (w ReLu) -> Pool -> Lrn
    conv1 = conv(self.X, 11, 11, 96, 4, 4, padding = 'VALID', name = 'conv1')
    pool1 = max_pool(conv1, 3, 3, 2, 2, padding = 'VALID', name = 'pool1')
    norm1 = lrn(pool1, 2, 2e-05, 0.75, name = 'norm1')

        # 2nd Layer: Conv (w ReLu) -> Pool -> Lrn with 2 groups
    conv2 = conv(norm1, 5, 5, 256, 1, 1, groups = 2, name = 'conv2')
    pool2 = max_pool(conv2, 3, 3, 2, 2, padding = 'VALID', name ='pool2')
    norm2 = lrn(pool2, 2, 2e-05, 0.75, name = 'norm2')

        # 3rd Layer: Conv (w ReLu)
    conv3 = conv(norm2, 3, 3, 384, 1, 1, name = 'conv3')

        # 4th Layer: Conv (w ReLu) splitted into two groups
    conv4 = conv(conv3, 3, 3, 384, 1, 1, groups = 2, name = 'conv4')

        # 5th Layer: Conv (w ReLu) -> Pool splitted into two groups
    conv5 = conv(conv4, 3, 3, 256, 1, 1, groups = 2, name = 'conv5')
    pool5 = max_pool(conv5, 3, 3, 2, 2, padding = 'VALID', name = 'pool5')

        # 6th Layer: Flatten -> FC (w ReLu) -> Dropout
    flattened = tf.reshape(pool5, [-1, 6*6*256])
    fc6 = fc(flattened, 6*6*256, 4096, name='fc6',relu =True)
    dropout6 = dropout(fc6, self.KEEP_PROB)

        # 7th Layer: FC (w ReLu) -> Dropout
    fc7 = fc(dropout6, 4096, 4096, name = 'fc7',relu =False)
 #   dropout7 = dropout(fc7, self.KEEP_PROB)

        # 8th Layer: FC and return unscaled activations (for tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits)
    self.fc8 = fc(fc7, 4096, self.NUM_CLASSES, name='fc8',relu = False)



  def load_initial_weights(self, session):
    """
    As the weights from http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~guerzhoy/tf_alexnet/ come
    as a dict of lists (e.g. weights['conv1'] is a list) and not as dict of
    dicts (e.g. weights['conv1'] is a dict with keys 'weights' & 'biases') we
    need a special load function
    """

    # Load the weights into memory
    weights_dict = np.load(self.WEIGHTS_PATH, encoding = 'bytes').item()

    # Loop over all layer names stored in the weights dict
    for op_name in weights_dict:

      # Check if the layer is one of the layers that should be reinitialized
      if op_name not in self.SKIP_LAYER:

        with tf.variable_scope(op_name, reuse = True):

          # Loop over list of weights/biases and assign them to their corresponding tf variable
          for data in weights_dict[op_name]:

            # Biases
            if len(data.shape) == 1:

              var = tf.get_variable('biases', trainable = False)
              session.run(var.assign(data))

            # Weights
            else:

              var = tf.get_variable('weights', trainable = False)
              session.run(var.assign(data))



"""
Predefine all necessary layer for the AlexNet
"""
def conv(x, filter_height, filter_width, num_filters, stride_y, stride_x, name,
         padding='SAME', groups=1):
  """
  Adapted from: https://github.com/ethereon/caffe-tensorflow
  """
  # Get number of input channels
  input_channels = int(x.get_shape()[-1])

  # Create lambda function for the convolution
  convolve = lambda i, k: tf.nn.conv2d(i, k,
                                       strides = [1, stride_y, stride_x, 1],
                                       padding = padding)

  with tf.variable_scope(name) as scope:
    # Create tf variables for the weights and biases of the conv layer
    weights = tf.get_variable('weights', shape = [filter_height, filter_width, input_channels/groups, num_filters])
    biases = tf.get_variable('biases', shape = [num_filters])


    if groups == 1:
      conv = convolve(x, weights)

    # In the cases of multiple groups, split inputs & weights and
    else:
      # Split input and weights and convolve them separately
      #input_groups = tf.split(value=x, num_split= groups, split_dim=3)
      #input_groups = tf.split(split_dim=3, num_split= groups,value=x)
      input_groups = tf.split(axis = 3, num_or_size_splits=groups, value=x)
     # weight_groups = tf.split(value =weights, num_split=groups, split_dim=3)
      weight_groups = tf.split(axis = 3, num_or_size_splits=groups, value=weights)

      output_groups = [convolve(i, k) for i,k in zip(input_groups, weight_groups)]

      # Concat the convolved output together again
      #conv = tf.concat( values = output_groups,concat_dim = 3)
      conv = tf.concat(axis = 3, values = output_groups)


    # Add biases
    bias = tf.reshape(tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases), conv.get_shape().as_list())

    # Apply relu function
    relu = tf.nn.relu(bias, name = scope.name)

    return relu

#def fc(x, num_in, num_out, name, relu = True):
def fc(x, num_in, num_out, name, relu):
  with tf.variable_scope(name) as scope:

    # Create tf variables for the weights and biases
    weights = tf.get_variable('weights', shape=[num_in, num_out], trainable=True)
    biases = tf.get_variable('biases', [num_out], trainable=True)

    # Matrix multiply weights and inputs and add bias
    act = tf.nn.xw_plus_b(x, weights, biases, name=scope.name)

    if relu == True:
      # Apply ReLu non linearity
      relu = tf.nn.relu(act)
      return relu
    else:
      return act


def max_pool(x, filter_height, filter_width, stride_y, stride_x, name, padding='SAME'):
  return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, filter_height, filter_width, 1],
                        strides = [1, stride_y, stride_x, 1],
                        padding = padding, name = name)

def lrn(x, radius, alpha, beta, name, bias=1.0):
  return tf.nn.local_response_normalization(x, depth_radius = radius, alpha = alpha,
                                            beta = beta, bias = bias, name = name)

def dropout(x, keep_prob):
  return tf.nn.dropout(x, keep_prob)
```

Now the code for the loss function ad optimizer is

```
   # Op for calculating the loss
with tf.name_scope("cross_ent"):
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(score, y))

    # Train op
with tf.name_scope("train"):
      # Get gradients of all trainable variables
    gradients = tf.gradients(loss, var_list)
    gradients = list(zip(gradients, var_list))

      # Create optimizer and apply gradient descent to the trainable variables
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)
    train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars=gradients)
```

Anything I should change in this part?
Or any comments, or anything I should take care of to change the model from classifcation to regression.
I am new to tensorflow and deep learning